# Import default value in import product price

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, import-products

I have multistore in magento 1.9 site. Like au,us and ca I use following csv to import prices.

**No** | **store** |    **sku**  |  **price**

- au => MYSKU 20
- us => MYSKU 30
- ca => MYSJU 31

But this will set stores vice prices.

**so how can we set default price?**

Comment: you need to use website instead of store value.

Comment: But I successfully imported products with store code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **leave one blank column** to import default value.

Your final csv like this:

```
No | store | sku | price

1           MYSKU  15
2    au     MYSKU  20
3    us     MYSKU  30
4    ca     MYSJU  31
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working. Now I want to set default select associated product of configurable product by csv. So which column I need to add in csv for this task?

Comment: @Rahul Create another question for this question.